# Вывод без тысячных, например 1.44 а не 1.444444

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, есть js калькулятор, как сделать чтобы выводилось, без тычечных дробей заранее спасибо!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function round_mod(value, precision) {
        var precision_number = Math.pow(10, precision);
        return Math.round(value * precision_number) / precision_number;
    }

    function recalcsq(squarefield) {
        width = $('#width').val();
        lenght = $('#lenght').val();
        sqinbox = $('#sqinbox').val();
        if (squarefield == 0) {
            $('#square').val(width * lenght);
        }
        sq = round_mod($('#square').val(), 3) + round_mod(($(".calculator input:radio:checked").val() / 100) * $('#square').val(), 3);
        $('#squareid').text(sq);
        boxcount = round_mod(sq / sqinbox, 3);
        $('#boxcount').text(boxcount);
        recboxcount = Math.ceil(boxcount);
        $('#recboxcount').text(recboxcount);
        recboxsq = recboxcount * sqinbox;
        $('#recboxsq').text(recboxsq);

        price = $('#flprice').val();
        lefts = $('#codepriceleft').val();
        rights = $('#codepriceright').val();

        totalbox = price * recboxcount;
        $('#totalbox').text(lefts + ' ' + totalbox + ' ' + rights);
        $('.calculator input[name="quantity"]').val(recboxcount);
    }
    $('#width').keyup(function (event) {
        recalcsq(0);
    });
    $('#lenght').keyup(function (event) {
        recalcsq(0);
    });
    $('#square').keyup(function (event) {
        recalcsq(1);
    });
    $('input[name="calc_type"]').change(function (event) {
        recalcsq(1);
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $('#button-cart2').bind('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('.calculator input[type=\'text\'], .calculator input[type=\'hidden\'], .calculator input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .calculator input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .calculator select, .calculator textarea'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

                if (json['error']) {
                    if (json['error']['option']) {
                        for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                            $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (json['success']) {
                    $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
                    $(".heading i").html('<img title="Очистить корзину" onclick="$(\'#cart\').load(\'index.php?route=module/cart&remove_all=1\' + \' #cart > *\'); return false;" style="cursor:pointer;" src="catalog/view/image/delete.png" />');
                    $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 'slow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    //-->
</script>
```

Вот это за вывод отвечает

```
recboxsq = recboxcount * sqinbox;
$('#recboxsq').text(recboxsq);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем вы весь этот код выкладывали...

```
var num = 1.44444;
alert(num.toFixed(2)); // 1.44
```

Comment: Не до конца понимаю, как применить к моему коду, я очень плох в js

Comment: @bajex смотрел по диагонали, вроде так:

    $('#recboxsq').text(recboxsq.toFixed(2));

Comment: Спасибо огромное